# Does Ubuntu 12.04 LiveCD run Unity 2D or 3D or selects which one to run adaptively?

Tags: unity, 12.04, unity-2d, live-cd

In case I boot from an Ubuntu 12.04 LiveCD, am I going to see Unity 2D, standard Unity ("3D") or does it depend on my hardware?

Answer (score 2):

As with an installed system,

```
/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test
```

will be used to determine whether the system is capable of running Unity 3d. If it is not, logically Ubuntu 2d will be started.

```
    /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
```

returns a nice little overview that tells you more about the hardware capabilities of your GPU.

Answer (score 1):

The live session will attempt to run Unity 3D. If your system is not capable or lacks necessary hardware drivers, it will run Unity 2d.